# Associate with arguments

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

I am trying to associate PHP files with the PHP program. I did something like
this:

```
assoc .php=PhpScript
ftype PhpScript=C:\php\php.exe "%1" %*
```

but if I run a script like this:

```
sunday.php monday
```

The argument is not recognized. Am I doing something wrong?

https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a registry entry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.php
```

That was overriding everything else. Deleting that fixed the problem.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/-/a2d8f0ef-bf44-4e87-82d1-3d0d55c657de